# How to set filled color in react-chartjs-2 with gradient color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to fill the background color with the gradient color just like below image. I have tried multiple methods to achieve the gradient but failed in most of them.
[image]

This is what I have tried till now:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler,
} from "chart.js";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { colors, hexToRGB } from "@/constant/data";
import useDarkMode from "@/hooks/useDarkMode";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler
);
const LineChart = () => {
  const [isDark] = useDarkMode();

//using the variable to add gradient color

  const gradientColor = {
    type: "linear",
    x0: 0,
    y0: 0,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 1,
    colorStops: [
      { offset: 0, color: "rgba(126, 234, 184, 1)" },
      { offset: 0.5, color: "rgba(126, 234, 184, 0.7)" },
      { offset: 1, color: "rgba(126, 234, 184, 0)" },
    ],
  };
  const data = {
    labels: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: " data one",
        data: [
          80, 150, 180, 270, 210, 160, 160, 202, 265, 210, 270, 255, 290, 360,
          375,
        ],
        fill: true,

// adding the defined variable with gradient color in backgroundColor

        backgroundColor: gradientColor,
        borderColor: colors.primary,
        borderSkipped: "bottom",
        barThickness: 40,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
        pointBorderColor: "transparent",
        lineTension: 0.5,
        pointStyle: "circle",
        pointShadowOffsetX: 1,
        pointShadowOffsetY: 1,
        pointShadowBlur: 5,
      },
      {
        label: " data two",
        data: [
          80, 125, 105, 130, 215, 195, 140, 160, 230, 300, 220, 170, 210, 200,
          280,
        ],
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(126, 234, 184, 0.7)",
        borderColor: colors.success,
        borderSkipped: "bottom",
        barThickness: 40,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
        pointBorderColor: "transparent",
        lineTension: 0.5,
        pointStyle: "circle",
        pointShadowOffsetX: 1,
        pointShadowOffsetY: 1,
        pointShadowBlur: 5,
      },
      {
        label: " data three",
        data: [
          80, 99, 82, 90, 115, 115, 74, 75, 130, 155, 125, 90, 140, 130, 180,
        ],

//here i tried adding the gradient color directly but did not work

        fill: true,
        backgroundColor:
          "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(71,128,233,1) 5%, rgba(233,104,137,1) 68%)",
        borderColor: colors.danger,
        borderSkipped: "bottom",
        barThickness: 40,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
        pointBorderColor: "transparent",
        lineTension: 0.5,
        pointStyle: "circle",
        pointShadowOffsetX: 1,
        pointShadowOffsetY: 1,
        pointShadowBlur: 5,
      },
    ],
  };
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    tension: 0.3,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          color: isDark ? "#cbd5e1" : "#475569",
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          color: isDark ? "#334155" : "#e2e8f0",
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: isDark ? "#334155" : "#e2e8f0",
        },

        ticks: {
          color: isDark ? "#cbd5e1" : "#475569",
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Line options={options} data={data} height={350} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LineChart;
```

This is what I got from above code:
[image]

I guess this is possible using canvas but I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: you can try to use https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-gradient